# How to make popup text when you click on the link/item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, popup

I am sorry for extremely straight forward question for web developers...  would really appreciate your help here!

I have an image that I split into sections using `<\map>`

Example:

```
<map name="guessing_game">

<area alt="" title="" href="#1" shape="poly" coords="709,202,714,187,687,161,655,138,628,90,621,59,630,35,640,19,661,12,686,12,705,17,722,31,729,36,751,22,774,18,801,26,817,33,832,65,821,109" />


 <area alt="" title="" href="#2" shape="poly" coords="275,363,280,350,240,317,202,268,189,227,200,193,219,178,247,178,264,175,285,193,295,204,313,189,342,183,369,186,392,202,400,231,395,267,363,309" />

<area alt="" title="" href="#3" shape="poly" coords="554,364,557,351,520,318,473,260,468,227,471,203,481,187,506,178,521,174,548,180,562,189,569,203,579,201,594,186,626,182,651,186,668,207,676,235,668,263,646,299" />
</map>
```

I would like to make a popup effect the same as in [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup)

So if someone will click on the link/aria they will get a different dialog.... with different position of the popup bubble.

Unfortunately I ran into the issue that if I try to use multiple text variations.... using the example above it will always return the same text no matter what link/aria I will click on.

```html
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}





/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -810px;  
    margin-bottom: 320px; 
}


.popup .popuptext2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -520px;  
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}



/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>


<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}


function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}


</script>




<img src="./image.jpg" alt="Picture" style="width:auto;max-width:100%" usemap="#guessing_game">


<map name="guessing_game">


<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
  <span class="popuptext1" id="myPopup"><strong>Header</strong><br> First variation</span>

 <area alt="Header" title="Header" shape="poly" coords="122,200,125,184,94,159,63,129,42,91,31,59,38,40,59,10,89,10,111,12,132,24,140,38,153,25,174,15,210,18,230,28,245,55,246,87,224,124,178,161" />
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
  <span class="popuptext2" id="myPopup2"><strong>Header 2</strong><br>Second text variation </span>
 <area alt="Header 2" title="Header 2" shape="poly" coords="417,200,419,183,389,160,336,97,327,61,339,26,356,14,380,11,404,13,418,20,432,34,450,28,477,17,508,19,535,41,536,81,525,112" />
</div>
```

please help... I am extremely sorry for such a basic question... I am sure there is a huge and simple mistake in the CSS or javascript function

Comment: No need to be so sorry, everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: Why do you need two myFunction() functions?

Comment: owww that is extremely embarrassing... This is clearly one of the mistakes I was talking about.... (essentially I duplicated it because I thought it would return the different text... but now I see that I don't need to create the same exact function! thank you! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be [passing in the context of `this`](https://jsfiddle.net/hzvc6s5n/3/) to your onclick handler

`onclick="myFunction(this)`

```
function myFunction(el) {
console.log(el);
    var popup = el;
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much unicorn2!

Now if I create separate function for different dialogs it will work just fine...

Here is how I do it now...
First I create different classes for different positions:

```html
.popup .popuptext1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -810px;  
    margin-bottom: 320px; 
}


.popup .popuptext2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -520px;  
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}
```

Then I create functions for different dialogs

```html
function dialog1() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("dialog1");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");

    
}
function dialog2() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("dialog2");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");

    
}
```

And after that I apply it to the image

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="dialog1()">
  <span class="popuptext1" id="dialog1"><strong>Header 1</strong><br> Text that is different from the second one!</span>

 <area alt="Header" title="Header" shape="poly" coords="122,200,125,184,94,159,63,129,42,91,31,59,38,40,59,10,89,10,111,12,132,24,140,38,153,25,174,15,210,18,230,28,245,55,246,87,224,124,178,161" />
</div>





<div class="popup" onclick="dialog2()">
  <span class="popuptext2" id="dialog2"><strong>Header 2</strong><br>Thext that is not the same as the first one</span>
 <area alt="Header2" title="Header2" shape="poly" coords="417,200,419,183,389,160,336,97,327,61,339,26,356,14,380,11,404,13,418,20,432,34,450,28,477,17,508,19,535,41,536,81,525,112" />
</div>
```

I wish I knew some better slick way of doing it... than creating different functions for different dialogs... but I am too unexperienced  yet.

Thank you <3 
I hope this will help some newbies like me in future!